# reconfigure roll of bones without losing waightpaint

Tags: rigging, bones

I need to change roll of some bones in my rig and would like to save my weight paint so I does not need to re-do it again. Is this possible. I know that I can change roll of finger bones with out deforming mesh but I cant to the same on legs :) Any thoughts :)

Answer (score 2):

Changing the roll of bones will not effect your weight painting and your model in rest-position will be exactly the same.

What will change is your bones pose transformations -> your armature in pose mode will look different. That's because such transformations are in local space and changing the roll of bones changes the bone's coordinate system base around it's Y axis.

Comment: Yes that's right, and how can I then switch x axis in order to have flipped pose across axis where I need them :) Tnx for helping out :)